# How to show the tags of an array of ggplots made with the patchwork package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend, patchwork

I have 5 plots that I want to organize in 2 columns: the first with 2 plots and the second with 3 plots. I used the `patchwork` package and the arrangement was the way I want it, but the tags don't appear even though I declared them in the `plot_annotation` command.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p <- ggplot()

plots <- (p/p)|(p/p/p) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "a")
plots
```

[image]

If I modify the layout, the tags appear. Note that when changing `|` by `+` tags appear

```
plots <- (p/p)+(p/p/p) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "a")
plots
```

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to wrap all plots before annotation:

```
((p/p)|(p/p/p)) +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "a")
```

[image]